# How to display the related list "Last Modified Date'' in Account object without trigger

Tags: account, related-list, lastmodifieddate

We have a need where the Related List Last Modified Date to be displayed in their respective Account Object without using any Triggers.

Its like whenever there is a change in Last Modified Date of Related Lists(Opportunity,Contact,Quote,Activities...)It should be displayed in a custom field of Account Object.

Suggestions Please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can update using workflow rule.when we have last modified date of contacts then we can pass these date in Account Field.And you will fill the criteria and then you can update.